# How to asynchronously run functions within a for-loop in Python?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

Hi I was wondering how to asynchronously call a function within a for-loop in Python, allowing the for-loop to execute more quickly. bar() in this case is a time intensive function, which is why I want the calls to it to be nonblocking.
Here is what I want to refactor:

```
def bar(item):
    //manipulate item
    return newItem

newItems = []
for item in items:
    newItem = foo(item)
    newItems.append[newItem]
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
async def bar(item):
    //manipulate item
    return newItem

async def foo():
    newItems = [bar(item) for item in items]
    newItems = await asyncio.gather(*newItems)
    return newItems

newItems = asyncio.run(foo())
```

This doesn't seem to work as each function call still waits for the previous one to finish before starting. I would love tips on what I might be doing wrong. Thank you so much for any and all help!

Comment: You may need to utilize Python's multiprocessibng capability for what you are doing since, async is usually only useful in speeding things up if you have an I/O operation which needs to wait. see[Speeding Up Python with Concurrency, Parallelism, and asyncio](https://testdriven.io/blog/concurrency-parallelism-asyncio/) for further clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your tasks are really async you can do it the following way:

```py
import asyncio


async def bar(item: int) -> int:
    # manipulate item
    print("Started")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Finished")
    return item ** 2


async def foo():
    items = range(1, 10)
    tasks = [bar(item) for item in items]
    new_items = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return new_items

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = asyncio.run(foo())
    print(results)
```

Comment: Perhaps my issues stem from my ignorance of what makes certain functions "really async" as I thought I could make any function asynchronous. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @plynch714 well if my answer solves the question for async tasks, please mark it as solution. Actually if your tasks are not async, for CPU heave tasks use `multiprocessing` module.